# Rename Excel Sheets with names from a List

Tags: c#, excel, list

I am trying to rename worksheets in an Excel workbook. Can anyone please tell me what I'm missing or doing wrong?

```
        //Execute Excel
        Excel.Application ex = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
        ex.Visible = true;
        ex.DisplayAlerts = false;
        //Create workbook
        Excel.Workbook wb = ex.Workbooks.Add();
        //Create sheets with names
        List<string> names = new List<string> {"03 SHEET 03","02 SHEET 02","01 SHEET 01"};
        foreach (string name in names) 
        {
            wb.Worksheets.Add().Name = name;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code example works with little adjustment. I just changed Excel initialization from `new Excel.ApplicationClass()` to `new Excel.Application()`. Here is my full code:

```
static void Main()
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ex = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    ex.Visible = true;
    ex.DisplayAlerts = false;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = ex.Workbooks.Add();
    var names = new List<string> { "03 SHEET 03", "02 SHEET 02", "01 SHEET 01" };

    foreach (string name in names)
    {
        wb.Worksheets.Add().Name = name;
    }
}
```

Of course, I had to add the reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` library. If you have any other issues, please provide more details about the errors (compile, runtime exception).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm having this problem  in the part
 wb.Worksheets.Add().Name = name;
when building the solution: "'object' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Build failed.
Coul you please tell me what is happening here?

Comment: Which assembly are you using? I am using library 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel' with description 'Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library' (Excel 2013). I think your code seems to be using Interop, but you are referencing to other library. For me it also works firstly add worksheet `wb.Worksheets.Add();` and then in second step rename it  `wb.ActiveSheet.Name = name;`

Comment: I am also using library 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel' with description 'Microsoft Excel 15.0. I don't know why it is not recognizing ".Name" definition.

Comment: Could you pack the project, store it somewhere and send the link?

Comment: I was working with SharpDevelop because that software is used by default when writing macros for Autodesk Revit. I have shifted to Visual Studio and working it as an external plugin and now is working fine. So, thank you!

Comment: Great! Good to hear it is working. I thought it must be some wrong reference.